# How would I get a little piece of HTML code out of a string? C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get a select HTML field out of my C# application.

The HTML that can come in are as follows...

```
<HTML>
    <BODY BGCOLOR="#123456">
        HELLO
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

This HTML can change anytime, the part of the HTML I want is the value for BGCOLOR e.g. #123456

or it could be "white", or "red", etc...

How can I do this?

I don't think substring would work as i can't predict how long the field would be.

Thanks

Comment: Try searching the site for "C# HTML Parsing" or "C# HTML Scraping"  It'll get you hundreds of answers that all say: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for parsing HTML.

So parsing something like `BGCOLOR` might look like:

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(someHtml);

var body = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
string bgColor = body.Attributes["bgcolor"].Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an XPath query.

see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333

Load the HTML into an XmlDocument and query it using "HTML/BODY@BGCOLOR"

Comment: The HTML provided in the question is valid, however if the HTML were to be invalid, I think you would encounter exceptions when attempting to load it into an `XmlDocument`.

Comment: html is not valid xml. For one thing, its not case sensitive. Another is that closing tags are not required